# What are the frequency dependent design components of microphones?

Tags: microphone

I would like to know what are the frequency limiting design factors and components in microphones? Why are some microphones able to detect sound up to 100kHz and others only 20kHz? I know that the capsule size is a factor, but then the the capsule size also has a direct relationship to self-noise.

Comment: I bet someone on the physics stack could answer this.